# Display the product image in shipment email template in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I need to display the  the product image in shipment email template.

```
$_item = $block->getItem();
$productId = $_item->getProductId();
$objectManagerHere = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManagerHere->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$productImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($product, 'category_page_list', array('height' => '150' , 'width'=> '150'))->getUrl();
<img width="65" src="<?= $productImage ?>" 
            alt="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"/>
```

But i gets only placeholder image url.....How to get the image url

Comment: category_page_list changes `product_base_image` see  what happen

Comment: Did you found this solution, Please let me know